# Java Map with multiple keys, and a count as value

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm working on creating some graphing software for a small business.  They gave me a report of their sales last year, and on this report it shows the "timestamp" and the item or "sku" for each specific sale, but in no particular order.  I'm suppose to figure out how many of each item sold on a particular day.  I know that I'm suppose to use map, but I'm not too familiar with how to use it in this case.  I also need for the map to return 0 if for a sku sold 0 items on a particular day.   This is difficult, because I don't know how many skus there will be on the report and the report is in no particular order.

For example the report could show:

```
sku="AKD123"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="AKD123"; timestamp="2012-04-14";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="PIK383"; timestamp="2012-10-07";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="PIK383"; timestamp="2012-03-01";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
```

How am I suppose to have a map that I can check how many "REN134" sold on "2012-02-01" to hopefully get a return of 4.

I hope I'm being clear enough.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a database?  Sticking that information in a table would make getting the counts you want a snap.

Comment: take a look at Apache Commons Collections [MultiValueMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two maps, one to match one `sku` to some dates and a count, and the one that maps each date to a count ...  Try this ...

```
final static String skus[] = {
    "AKD123",
    "AKD123",
    "REN134",
    "PIK383",
    "REN134",
    "REN134",
    "PIK383",
    "REN134"
};

final static String timestamp[] = {
    "2012-02-01",
    "2012-04-14",
    "2012-02-01",
    "2012-10-07",
    "2012-02-01",
    "2012-02-01",
    "2012-03-01",
    "2012-02-01"
};


@Test
public void countSkusPerDay() {
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> countMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < skus.length; i++) {
        String sku = skus[i];
        String date = timestamp[i];
        Map<String, Integer> countPerDateMap = countMap.get(sku);
        if(countPerDateMap == null) {
            countPerDateMap = new HashMap<>();
            countMap.put(sku, countPerDateMap);
        }
        Integer count = countPerDateMap.get(date);
        if(count == null) {
            countPerDateMap.put(date, 1);
        } else {
            countPerDateMap.put(date, count.intValue() + 1);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, Integer>> e : countMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("sku " + e.getKey() + " sold in " + e.getValue().size() + " day(s) " + e.getValue());
    }
}
```

Output is

```
sku REN134 sold in 1 day(s) {2012-02-01=4}
sku PIK383 sold in 2 day(s) {2012-10-07=1, 2012-03-01=1}
sku AKD123 sold in 2 day(s) {2012-02-01=1, 2012-04-14=1}
```

Answer (score 3):

A Map can't have duplicate keys.  What you will need to do is have a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` or something of that sort, where the key is the SKU number and the value is a list of all dates which you can then use for further sorting and processing to count the occurrences.

Comment: Perhaps a Map<String, Map<Date,Integer>> might also be useful - internal map is a map from date to count.

Comment: Sure, you can always store more associative information by going "deeper" with nested Maps.  Nice suggestion, depending on how complex the OP wants to get and whether readability is a concern (I personally find lots of nested maps a little obfuscating, but that's just me).

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code (I've added your sample data)...its taking advantage of the fact that Map can't have duplicate keys:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class TEST
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
/*
sku="AKD123"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="AKD123"; timestamp="2012-04-14";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="PIK383"; timestamp="2012-10-07";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";
sku="PIK383"; timestamp="2012-03-01";
sku="REN134"; timestamp="2012-02-01";

    Transform into this array:
*/
    String[] inputValues = new String[]
    { "AKD123|2012-02-01", "AKD123|2012-04-14", "REN134|2012-02-01", "PIK383|2012-10-07", "REN134|2012-02-01", "REN134|2012-02-01",
        "PIK383|2012-03-01", "REN134|2012-02-01" };

    // That is your map
    Map<String, Integer> mapCouter = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    // now iterate though all SKU sales
    for (String key : inputValues)
    {
      Integer count = mapCouter.get(key);
      if (count == null)
      {
        // not found... lets init.
        count = 0; // using java autoboxing.
      }
      mapCouter.put(key, ++count); // incrementing by 1 before storing in the Map
    }
    System.out.println("Report:");
    Set<String> keys = mapCouter.keySet();
    for (String key : keys)
    {
      System.out.println("key: " + key + " has " + mapCouter.get(key) + " occurences.");
    }
  }
}
```

---

It produces the following output:

```
Report:
key: REN134|2012-02-01 has 4 occurences.
key: AKD123|2012-04-14 has 1 occurences.
key: PIK383|2012-10-07 has 1 occurences.
key: AKD123|2012-02-01 has 1 occurences.
key: PIK383|2012-03-01 has 1 occurences.
```

**NOTE:** You would need to parse through the input file (since it could be big data) and use this "Map counter" technique shown.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `Item` class to encapsulate the `sku` and `timestamp` fields.  Implement the `hashCode` and `equals` methods so later a `HashMap` will work properly.

Create your map.

```
Map<Item, Integer> salesMap = new HashMap<Item, Integer>();
```

You'll need to initialize the map with values of 0 so that later you can get which items didn't have a sale in a day.

Read in the data from the report and create your `Item` objects.  If it doesn't exist in the map yet, then store it in the map with a value of 1.  If it does exist, then take the stored value, add 1, and store the new value.

Answer (score 0):

What about having a map of [Guava Multisets](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) like `Map<String,Multiset<String>> itemToDatesSoldMap = new HashMap<>();`. This would allow us to do something like

```
public int countSalesOfItemOnDate(String sku, String timestamp){
    Multiset<String> timestampMultiset = itemToDatesSoldMap.get(sku);
    if(timestampMultiset == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return timestampMultiset.count(timestamp);
}

countSalesOfItemOnDate("REN134","2012-02-01");
```